# How to install xpra 3.0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: xpra

I'm running Ubuntu Disco. Installing `xpra` from the standard repository gives me xpra 2.4, but I need 3.0.

**Possibile route.** I found a list of [releases](https://xpra.org/dists/disco/) here but don't know what to do with them.

**Another attempt.** I also tried the following:

```
sudo su -

apt-get install curl
curl https://xpra.org/gpg.asc | apt-key add -

echo "deb https://xpra.org/repos/disco/xpra.list disco main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xpra.list;
apt-get install -y software-properties-common >& /dev/null;
add-apt-repository universe >& /dev/null;
apt-get update;
apt-get install xpra;
```

from [here](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download) and [here](https://winswitch.org/downloads/debian-repository.html?dist_select=disco), which didn't seem to work (I get xpra 2.4 again).

Comment: The xpra package list can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xpra) for manual download

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is wrong, you are trying to add the repository file as a URL!
Just use this as URL:

```
https://xpra.org/ disco main
```